# Internet Explorer 7 CSS bug (Favorite Tags) - stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow, design, internet-explorer-7

Favorite tags seem to be split (screenshot below).

[image]

To reproduce:

1. Log in
2. Click on Questions tab
3. Scroll down to the Favorite Tags section (right pane)

Comment: IE7 is supported for functionality, but not display imperfections, per [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208).

Comment: Thanks! I did not know IE7 is minimally supported...

Comment: IE7 supports the css attribute `display: modern-art`.

Comment: If IE7 is not fully supported, does it mean users should not report bugs here? I found another bug and wonder what I should do... Meanwhile, I see some folks posting/reporting IE7 bugs. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: The best thing to do is **upgrade your browser**. Fixes a bunch of sites other than Stack Overflow.

Comment: That's very funny!! I got 2 votes down for this question?! I do not get it. :) Does that mean those two people do not think there is a bug in IE7? or, they think the question is not appropriate? LOL. Meanwhile, market share of IE6 and IE7 combined is ~17% which is more than ALL versions of Chrome (~11%). I am not saying stackoverflow.com should have taken that into consideration. My point is, IE7 related bugs ARE affecting sizable number of stackoverflow users.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Your "suggestion" is not a solution whatsoever (see above). Meanwhile, I use Chrome for most of my stuff. But, at work, as for many (still) companies, IE7 is our standard browser. I do have Chrome and IE7 at work, though.

Comment: The downvotes mean that people disagree this issue is worth fixing. That's pretty standard on Meta (you can read more about downvotes in the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)). In particular, I don't think the developers should waste much time fixing cosmetic & UI issues in an obsolete browser like IE 7: it's time to upgrade. Everyone has their excuses. I still run Win NT 4 on a machine that I use for everyday work, so it's not like I'm clueless to the problem. I also wasn't proposing upgrading as a "solution". You asked "wonder what I should do"; I was answering that.